# Check if binary matrix exists with only 2 rows for given row and column sum

Tags: java, matrix

I have a binary matrix with only 2 rows and N columns.

The sum of elements in first row is A and sum of elements in 2nd row is B.

The sum of columns is stored in an array C.

```
If A = 3, B = 2, C = [2,1,1,0,1] Then output is "11001,10100"

Explanation:
11001 = sum of 1st row is A = 3
10100 = sum of 2nd row is B = 2

21101 --> This is column sum which indicates Array C.
```

Another example:

```
If A = 2, B = 3, C = [0,0,1,1,2] Then output is "NO"
```

I have written below program that is working for above test cases, but when I run this in an interview it passed only 40% test cases, can you please help me in solving this, what is the mistake in this program and how to correct this?

```
public static String process(int A, int B, int[] C) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int val : C) {
        total = total + val;
    }
    // Sums do not match so matrix is not possble
    if (total != A + B) {
        return "NO";
    } else {
        String first = "", second = "";

        boolean flag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
            // Both the columns must be 1
            if (C[i] == 2) {
                first += "1";
                second += "1";
            } else if (C[i] == 0) {
                // Both the columns must be 0
                first += "0";
                second += "0";
            } else {
                // Any one if the columns should be 1
                if (flag) {
                    first += "1";
                    second += "0";
                } else {
                    first += "0";
                    second += "1";
                }
                flag = !flag;
            }
        }
        return first + "," + second;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost, but here is where it goes wrong:

```
// Any one if the columns should be 1
```

Only considering this will mean your two matrices will satisfy the condition supplied by `C`, but not `A` and `B` since you're simply alternating for the case `C[i] == 1`.

Simplest case for where this breaks: `A = 2`, `B = 0` and `C = [1,1]`. Your program will print `"10,01"`, while it should be `"11,00"`.

So the trick here is: After handling the easy `C[i] == 0` and `C[i] == 2` cases, you have to figure out how many `1`s still have to go in both the first and second row.

Edit: A possible solution would be:

```
boolean flag = true;
int currentTopRowSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
// Both the columns must be 1
  if (C[i] == 2) {
    first += "1";
    second += "1";
  } else if (C[i] == 0) {
    // Both the columns must be 0
    first += "0";
    second += "0";
  } else {
    //This is where it went wrong, so I changed this.
    if (currentTopRowSum < A) {
      first += "1";
      second += "0";
      currentTopRowSum++;
    } else {
      first += "0";
      second += "1";
    }
  }
}
```

In short, you keep track of the sum of your top row and add `"1"` to that if you haven't met that criteria yet. If you have, add it to the bottom row instead.

Comment: can you please help me how to write this logic to find all possible sets?

Comment: sure, check my answer. It doesn't provide all possible solutions, but it'll provide a correct solution given constraints À`, `B`and `C`.